# Compressing using tar with bash script : Line n is a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new with bash script and now trying to make a back-up file using it. What I'm facing is below script (line 47 in my bash file),

`$(tar -czvPf ${folder_backup}/rajal/backup.tgz -C /var/www/tmk/app .)`

always gimme  error on the shell `./test: line 47: ./: Is a directory`, while it works on Terminal, nicely.

FYI, folder app is folder with files and subfolders.

Could someone help me out? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why do you have `$( )` around the tar?

Comment: @Mat I just follow prev example, said $(PWD). Because I still new, I still have no idea if am doing wrong or what.. So, that's it.. Learning by doing. And since it didn't throw any error, so I keep using it, till you ask me why I have it :D

Comment: @Mat thank you! I removed it and bamm... It works! What a shame.. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(command)
```

means: execute `command` and return its output. To illustrate, it is very often used like this:

```
result=$(foo 4 123)
```

After this is evaluated, `result` will hold whatever the command `foo 4 123` output.

If you use that construct directly - not as an argument to another command, or in a variable assignment, the shell will try to *execute the output of the command*. While this is sometimes wanted, it often is not, and that's what you're seeing.

So just remove the `$( )` from your command and run `tar` directly. If you want to capture the output of `tar`, either redirect it to a file or use the construct above.

---

Do note that `$(command)` and `${env_var_name}` are completely different. Syntax matters.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mat `Why do you have $( ) around the tar?`, so i just removed it and it is working now :D